# Add local PKCS11 JAR in Gradle dependencies so it resolves for subdependencies

Tags: java, gradle

We're building an API that uses a government provided set of libraries. However in their dependencies `com.sun.security:pkcs11:1.0` is listed, which is not a public package. They are so kind as to provide this jar.

Aside from the dubious legality of this, I am not sure how to actually include this in our Gradle project. I tried this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

But alas, this does not resolve. Any idea how to tackle this? I am pretty new to Gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the source is local and reference it with a relative path.

```
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'libs'
       }
    }

    dependencies {
       compile files('libs/the_local_file.jar')
   }
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It is still failing though, but it seems like they are referring to an unsigned jar somewhere for some reason. 
```FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find pkcs11-unsigned.jar (com.sun.security:pkcs11:1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/C:/Users/vande/Documents/micro-vsbnet-connector/libs/pkcs11-1.0-unsigned.jar
      file:/C:/Users/vande/Documents/micro-vsbnet-connector/libs/pkcs11-unsigned.jar```

Comment: Let's try to break things, shall we? Just get the jar you have and add the '-unsigned' to it, place in the same folder of the mentioned on the path and try again. If you are lucky, it will work so you can at least get started on your work until you figure out how to properly set up the environment.

Comment: Renaming it works. Feels so dirty though, but thanks!

Comment: Well it feels dirty because it probably is! It is very likely that there is some "process" to make it work correctly... at least I hope the process is not the one we just did. My suggestion of renaming the file was based on previous experience building Android .apk. If you don't add a certificate to it, you come up with a `yourApp_unsiged.apk`. Other than the 'signing', the apk is just the same in content and work just as a signed one. So I asked you to try the above, *until* you find someone who can explain how to correctly set things up ;). Until then, happy coding!